# I can't store to eeprom when * is pressed

Tags: arduino

I have a problem , I am trying to get the key pressed in a keypad and store them in EEPROM and read the EEPROM when a key is pressed. In this case the key is "*"

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>
#include<EEPROM.h>
int i=0;

static char liters[4];
const byte rows = 4; //number of the keypad's rows and columns
const byte cols = 4;

char keys [rows] [cols] = { //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypad
    {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
    {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
    {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
    
byte rowPins [rows] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; //pins of the keypad
byte colPins [cols] = {8, 9, 10, 11};
    
Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
  
void loop() {
    if (i<4) {
        char key = myKeypad.getKey();
        if (key) {
            liters[i]=key;
           Serial.println(key);
            EEPROM.write(i,key);
            i++;
            //    delay(300);
            //    Serial.print(EEPROM.read(i));
        }
    }
    if (key=='*') {
         Serial.print(EEPROM.read(i));
    }
```

When the key * is pressed the keys that were pressed will be stored in the EEPROM. I don't know why the code is not working  please help

Comment: Seems like a arduino code. How about adding the arduino tag?

Comment: Also, read the description of the two tags you applied and remove the wrong one. Oh, and format the code if you want people to read it. The above makes it difficult to even recognize the structure.

Comment: Please focus on one problem you have. In this qustion, do you want to ask about reading from keypad or about storing something to EEPROM? Separating those two parts might also help you with debugging.

Comment: When a key is pressed, do you want to store into EEPROM or read from EEPROM? Or both? Please elaborate.

Comment: You have `char key = myKeypad.getKey();` twice in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if(key=='*'){
   Serial.print(EEPROM.read(i));
}
```

is in the outer of two scope in wich you have a `char key = myKeypad.getKey();` each.
It hence uses the outer `key`, which uses the first key read from keyboard, while the inner scope uses the second read key.
Whatever problem you observe, it is probably caused by the two read keys being different.